Dynamic Arrays with Count / Capacity in C
I write in C for several projects (e.g. learning / teaching,
coding competitions, data processing) and frequently need
arrays (e.g. strings) with fast appending / concatenation / reversing.
I've isolated the code below from a project. For simplicity,
I assume all arguments are valid, including no pointer aliasing
(for each function, no two arguments point to overlapping blocks of memory).
I use a doubling strategy on reallocation.
I understand that vector and string from C++ likely
have superior performance / features - this is for settings where a simple C solution is more accessible or
easier to modify for the specific context of the problem.
stringi.h
#include <assert.h>

// contiguous dynamic array for fixed-size type T
// note: v[] is not terminated (no '\0')
typedef struct {
    char *v; // T *v (testing: T = char)
    size_t count; // count <= capacity
    size_t capacity; // sizeof(v) / sizeof(T)
} stringi_raw;

// safe non-method mutations:
// 1. modifying v[i] for indices i
//      e.g. v[i] = 'a'; ++v[i];
// 2. if n <= count, assigning n to count will keep
// the first n elements; beware of underflow!
//      e.g. while (count > 0) --count;

// maximum capacity: capacity <= CAP_MAX
// practical: CAP_MAX = SIZE_MAX / sizeof(T)
static const size_t CAP_MAX = 987654321;

// pointer to a stringi_raw
typedef stringi_raw *stringi;

// initializes a stringi with 0 elements
// to be deallocated by stringi_free
stringi stringi_init();

// frees memory used by target from the heap
void stringi_free(stringi target);

// allow n items to be stored without realloc
// note: assumes n <= CAP_MAX
void stringi_reserve(stringi target, size_t n);

// appends c to the end of target
// note: takes O(1) amortized time
void stringi_put(stringi target, char c);

// appends the contents of src to dst
void stringi_cat(stringi dst, const stringi src);

// reverses target->v
void stringi_reverse(stringi target);

// aka "reverse(src); cat(dst, src); reverse(src)"
void stringi_cat_rev(stringi dst, const stringi src);

stringi.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stringi.h"

stringi stringi_init()
{
    stringi target = malloc(sizeof(stringi_raw));
    assert(target != NULL);

    target->v = NULL; // realloc(NULL, x) = malloc(x)
    target->count = 0;
    target->capacity = 0;
    return target;
}

void stringi_free(stringi target)
{
    free(target->v); // free(NULL) is safe
    free(target);
}

// sets the capacity of target to cap
// note: assumes count <= cap <= CAP_MAX
void stringi_set_cap(stringi target, size_t cap)
{
    void *v = realloc(target->v, cap * sizeof(char));
    assert(v != NULL);

    target->v = v;
    target->capacity = cap;
}

// get the next capacity from cap
size_t double_or_max(size_t cap)
{
    if (cap > CAP_MAX / 2)
        return CAP_MAX;
    return 2 * cap;
}

void stringi_reserve(stringi target, size_t n)
{
    size_t cap = target->capacity;
    if (n > cap)
    {
        if (cap == 0)
            cap = 1;
        else
        {
            cap = double_or_max(cap);
            while (n > cap)
                cap = double_or_max(cap);   
        }

        stringi_set_cap(target, cap);
    }
}

void stringi_put(stringi target, char c)
{
    size_t n = target->count;

    assert(n < CAP_MAX);
    size_t n_fin = n + 1;
    stringi_reserve(target, n_fin);
    
    target->v[n] = c;
    target->count = n_fin;
}

void stringi_cat(stringi dst, const stringi src)
{
    size_t n_d = dst->count;
    size_t n_s = src->count;

    assert(n_d <= CAP_MAX - n_s);
    size_t n_fin = n_d + n_s;
    stringi_reserve(dst, n_fin);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_s; ++i)
        dst->v[n_d + i] = src->v[i];
    dst->count = n_fin;
}

// if min <= max, reverse v[min] to v[max] inclusive
void chars_reverse(char *v, size_t min, size_t max)
{
    while (min < max)
    {
        char temp = v[min];
        v[min] = v[max];
        v[max] = temp;
        ++min;
        --max;
    }
}

void stringi_reverse(stringi target)
{
    // avoid underflow when count = 0
    size_t count = target->count;
    if (count > 0)
        chars_reverse(target->v, 0, count - 1);
}

void stringi_cat_rev(stringi dst, const stringi src)
{
    size_t n_d = dst->count;
    size_t n_s = src->count;

    assert(n_d <= CAP_MAX - n_s);
    size_t n_fin = n_d + n_s;
    stringi_reserve(dst, n_fin);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_s; ++i)
        dst->v[n_fin - 1 - i] = src->v[i];
    dst->count = n_fin;
}

Tests
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include "stringi.h"

void stringi_remove(stringi *target)
{
    stringi_free(*target);
    *target = NULL;
}

void stringi_print(stringi target)
{
    printf("'%.*s' (%zu/%zu)\n",
        (unsigned int) target->count, target->v, 
        target->count, target->capacity);
}

void stringi_validate(stringi target, char *expected)
{
    size_t n = strlen(expected);
    assert(n == target->count);
    assert(0 == strncmp(expected, target->v, n));
}

int diff_to_ms(clock_t diff)
{
    return diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

clock_t time_putchar(stringi target)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < CAP_MAX; ++i)
        stringi_put(target, 'c');
    return clock() - start;
}

int main()
{
    assert(CAP_MAX >= 1);
    assert(CAP_MAX <= SIZE_MAX / sizeof(char));

    stringi s1 = stringi_init();
    stringi_validate(s1, "");
    printf("create: s1 = %p\n", s1);
    printf("\nexpanding s1:\n");

    stringi_reverse(s1);
    stringi_validate(s1, "");

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i)
    {
        stringi_print(s1);
        stringi_put(s1, 'a' + i);
    }

    stringi_validate(s1, "abcdefghijklm");
    stringi_print(s1);

    stringi s2 = stringi_init();
    stringi_validate(s2, "");
    printf("\ncreate: s2 = %p\n", s2);

    for (int i = 13; i < 26; ++i)
        stringi_put(s2, 'a' + i);
    stringi_validate(s2, "nopqrstuvwxyz");

    stringi_cat(s1, s2);
    stringi_validate(s1, 
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

    stringi_reverse(s1);
    stringi_validate(s1,
        "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba");

    s2->count = 2;
    stringi_validate(s2, "no");

    stringi_cat(s1, s2);
    stringi_validate(s1, 
        "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbano");

    stringi_cat_rev(s1, s2);
    stringi_validate(s1,
        "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbanoon");

    stringi_remove(&s1);
    printf("remove: s1 = %p\n", s1);
    stringi_remove(&s2);
    printf("remove: s2 = %p\n", s2);

    s1 = stringi_init();
    stringi_validate(s1, "");
    printf("create: s1 = %p\n", s1);

    s2 = stringi_init();
    stringi_validate(s2, "");
    printf("create: s2 = %p\n", s2);

    int diff1 = diff_to_ms(time_putchar(s1));
    printf("\ns1 += CAP_MAX * 'c': %d ms\n", diff1);
    stringi_cat(s1, s2);

    // expect error: exceeding CAP_MAX
    // stringi_put(s1, 'c');

    s1->count = 0;
    stringi_validate(s1, "");
    printf("clear s1:\n");
    stringi_print(s1);
    stringi_remove(&s1);

    stringi_reserve(s2, CAP_MAX);
    printf("\nreserve for s2: CAP_MAX\n");
    int diff2 = diff_to_ms(time_putchar(s2));
    printf("s2 += CAP_MAX * 'c': %d ms\n", diff2);

    s2->count = 0;
    stringi_validate(s2, "");
    printf("clear s2:\n");
    stringi_print(s2);
    stringi_remove(&s2);

    return 0;
}

Output
create: s1 = 0000015E9D66F050

expanding s1:
'' (0/0)
'a' (1/1)
'ab' (2/2)
'abc' (3/4)
'abcd' (4/4)
'abcde' (5/8)
'abcdef' (6/8)
'abcdefg' (7/8)
'abcdefgh' (8/8)
'abcdefghi' (9/16)
'abcdefghij' (10/16)
'abcdefghijk' (11/16)
'abcdefghijkl' (12/16)
'abcdefghijklm' (13/16)

create: s2 = 0000015E9D66EEB0
remove: s1 = 0000000000000000
remove: s2 = 0000000000000000
create: s1 = 0000015E9D66EF90
create: s2 = 0000015E9D66F110

s1 += CAP_MAX * 'c': 1120 ms
clear s1:
'' (0/987654321)

reserve for s2: CAP_MAX
s2 += CAP_MAX * 'c': 931 ms
clear s2:
'' (0/987654321)

I would appreciate any thoughts on performance, readability, or modifiability.

A short note, not worth an answer. Toby below pointed out your use of assert is wrong. In the function stringi_set_cap you have the comment "assumes count <= cap <= CAP_MAX". That assumption should be checked with an assert. That is exactly what asserts are for. It'll be there when debugging, so the user can see when they call your functions in the wrong way, but won't be there in production, to not slow down the function.

I understand that vector and string from C++ likely have superior performance - not for large reallocations, where this is about 2x faster with 70x fewer page faults.  C realloc is far superior to C++ new/delete which omits any way to grow an existing allocation.  Of course you need link-time optimization to inline across C source files to reduce per-push overhead since you put all your tiny functions in a separate .c instead of directly in the .h with static inline (or inline plus a .c with extern inline instantiation).

@PeterCordes Your comment intrigued me so much that I decided to benchmark vs std::vector for 7 billion push_back operations. The code above takes 56176 ms without optimizations and 18947 ms with optimizations, while std::vector takes 485778 ms without optimizations and 10968 ms with optimizations. Unfortunately, the optimized executable for my code appears to be causing a ton of branch mispredictions (I have no idea what magic causes std::vector to avoid this).

Benchmarking without optimization is not interesting, especially for heavily templated C++ code that relies on a lot of inlining of tiny functions. (Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?).  Did you compile with clang or gcc -flto or gcc -fwhole-program to allow cross-file inlining from your stringi.c, if your benchmark was in a different file?  Can you link your benchmark code, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ (with compiler version/options you actually used) so I can see what you did and maybe profile it on my own Skylake system? Also what CPU?

Here's a link using godbolt - seems like stringi is now faster. Would appreciate any benchmarking thoughts you have. https://godbolt.org/z/oxM85feax

@JustinChang - didn't see your comment right away since you forgot to @ notify me.  First of all, you forgot to enable optimization on Godbolt so of course std::vector is much slower, especially when you test it first so any CPU-frequency or other warmup effects hit it harder.  Idiomatic way of performance evaluation? .  With optimization enabled, they run at about similar speeds on my Skylake when I raise CAP_MAX to 10000000, like vector 1206 +- 10 ms, stringi around 1280 ms.

I notice in the asm the stringi loop is storing some 64-bit values and reloading others every iteration.  This might just be a shortage of registers, since I don't think there's a store/reload of the same value other than in the basic block that calls realloc (from looking at the asm, simplified by commenting out the std::vector part: https://godbolt.org/z/bx5rYvh5c).  char* can alias anything, but the compiler probably managed to prove that char *v; isn't pointing at itself or the count or capacity, otherwise it would need to store them and reload them around every byte store.

If this wasn't all inlined into main which does the allocating, like a more realistic use-case where you have a separate function that gets an already-allocated stringi, you would have this aliasing problem unless maybe you used char *restrict v.  But that would make it unsafe (undefined behaviour) to access the string buffer with any other pointers that weren't derived from v, which might be ok...

Anyway, your benchmark does a modulo with % 64 every iteration, which costs a movabs r64, imm64 and a 64-bit mul and some shift / LEA for each byte, which is maybe a similar amount of overhead to the bookkeeping to check if realloc is needed.  I'm seeing negligible branch mispredicts with perf stat on Skylake, miss rate is 0.00%.  IPC is 3.41 instructions per clock. It's not getting optimized away despite not doing anything with the results except read the count, at least not by GCC.  Clang can be more aggressive about optimizing away alloc/free even for code that writes the to buffer.

Anyway, remember that the big gains in realloc vs. new+copy+delete come with very large buffers, like multiple GiB, where copying really sucks compared to page-table tricks.  Easier to see with int where the one-at-a-time push part of the work goes 4x faster relative to the reallocations.

Appreciate the analysis @PeterCordes. My next steps will probably be more correctness tests and a test case that makes the compiler's job harder.

Simplifying to s1.push_back('a');, on my desktop I get 510 ms for std::vector doing 1GB with g++ -O3 GCC14.2. The main asm loop is just 4 instructions: a byte store (look for mov  BYTE PTR [r13+0], 97 in https://godbolt.org/z/qc3j6PnzY), a pointer increment and counter decrement, falling out of that loop for the next reallocation.  stringi does some storing of 64-bit values every iteration and a taken branch in the common case, running in 810 ms. (look for mov     BYTE PTR [r12+r14], 97, really just search for 97 which is 'a')

So yeah I think actually GCC isn't fully succeeding at alias analysis, so char * being allowed to alias anything hurts this, unlike with an int array.  Not sure how std::vector is  avoiding problems.

I don't like this typedef:

// pointer to a stringi_raw
typedef stringi_raw *stringi;


In C, it's important to know whether any value is a pointer or a value object.  Obscuring this distinction is harmful to my understanding.

This assert() is unfounded:

stringi target = malloc(sizeof(stringi_raw));
assert(target != NULL);


Assertions exist to tell us something that's true by design.  However, we know that malloc() can return a null pointer, and that's something that we need to handle - even (or especially) in production builds when automatic checking of our assertions is disabled by setting NDEBUG.  If our assertion is untrue, we proceed straight into undefined behaviour, and that's not something we should inflict on our users.

stringi_free() is safe when passed a string with no storage, but (unlike free()), it can't be passed a null pointer.  We could document that its target argument must be valid, but I think it's more helpful to users to just deal with null pointers:
void stringi_free(stringi target)
{
    if (!target) { return; }
    ⋮
}


stringi.h includes <assert.h>.  But that's not needed here - don't impose that cost on every translation unit that includes stringi.h.
Conversely, it is invalid if there isn't a definition of size_t in scope before it's included.
If stringi.h is included multiple times in a translation unit, I think we get errors from redefining stringi_raw.  And an include guard to avoid that problem.

In stringi.c, we have

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stringi.h"


This explains why we didn't spot the need for stringi.h to have size_t in scope.  If we include our header first, then that gives us confidence that it's complete and not dependent on any prior declarations.

The tests demonstrate the functionality, but always return a success status.  Better tests are self-checking, returning failure status if any of the operations don't produce the expected result.

Good answer. Note that stringi_free() assumes that the pointer argument is not null, so it is coupled to the behaviors of the assert()s after malloc() and realloc().

Appreciate the answer. I will likely alter the design so that it returns NULL for failed stringi_init() and int error codes for failed extending, leaving the asserts to the users. This would also make it easier to test failures by assert. And the order of includes is a great catch.

Thanks @Nayuki - I've added a note about stringi_free().

A few small items:

stringi stringi_init(): In C, an empty parameter list means any number of arguments, not zero arguments. Change this to stringi stringi_init(void). (This is not necessary in C++ or starting in C23.)

void chars_reverse(char *v, size_t min, size_t max): This function is only used within stringi.c, so make it "private" by adding static in front, like: static void chars_revers(...).

void stringi_cat(...): Replace the for-loop with memcpy():
memcpy(dst->v + n_d, src->v, n_s);


void stringi_reserve(...): Use a do-while loop:
do cap = double_or_max(cap);
while (n > cap);


It seems like the canonical definition of size_t exists in stddef.h.



Appreciate it! The do while is a lot cleaner.
